# Redshift Regex_Replace : using pattern in replace string

Tags: json, regex

My requirement is to split a json file in rows for each element within the json. I order to do that I've figure it out that the query to split by rows is something like this:

```
SELECT EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(json_string, '}, "ChIJA7Vlp5iZpBIRo8rMYZedIDo": {', '}\n{'), '\n')) AS json_exploded
```

Info: I'm connected to an EMR Cluster (spark under the hood) through a Thrift Server so that I can query json files from DataGrip.

But, to do so, I have replace this chunk of the string:

}, "ChIJA7Vlp5iZpBIRo8rMYZedIDo": {

by a '}\n{'

so then I will be available to split by row using the split.

So I should find first a pattern for this

```
}, "ChIJA7Vlp5iZpBIRo8rMYZedIDo": {
```

in order to replace it by this:

```
}\n{
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\w{27}` do the trick - matching 27 alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Ans probably escape THE OTHER curly parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which programming language you are using. Many languages support extract/replace by groups. The following regex contains three capturing groups

```
(.*\}, ")(\w*)(": \{.*)
```

```
$1 = SELECT EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(json_string, '}, "
$2 = ChIJA7Vlp5iZpBIRo8rMYZedIDo
$3 = ": {', '}\n{'), '\n')) AS json_exploded
```

Which can be refered to with `$1 $2 $3` or `\1 \2 \3` depending on the programming language that you are using.
The expression `$1\n$3` or `\1\n\3` would therefore equal `SELECT EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(json_string, '}, "\n": {', '}\n{'), '\n')) AS json_exploded`

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches `\d`

Comment: The fourth bird - Thank you. Is that true in all the flavours of regex? I had the idea that somewhere it hadn't worked.

Comment: If `\w` is supported, then I think it will always match digits 0-9. See [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Comment: The fourth bird  Thank you - thinking about it the problem might have been the other way round that I had a problem : I needed `[a-zA-Z]` and `\w` matched digits that I didn't want to accept. Thank you - I've learnt something today. :-)

Comment: @Kendle I just want to replace this chunk of the string:

}, "ChIJA7Vlp5iZpBIRo8rMYZedIDo": {

for this one  '}\n{'

Comment: What programming language are you using?